# WIX ブログページに月別アーカイブ機能を追加する方法

Tags: untagged

WIXを使ってWEBサイトを製作しております。

ブログのページに月別のアーカイブ機能をつけたいと考えておりますが、
どのようにカスタマイズすれば、月別のアーカイブが作れるか分かりません。

例）
・2020年１月（投稿件数）
・2020年２月（投稿件数）
・2020年３月（投稿件数）
・2020年４月（投稿件数）

このような月別リンクへの作成方法を知っている方がいましたら
教えていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: そのものの機能は無さそうです[Wixのブログ機能って使えるの？...](https://www.cherrypieweb.com/weblog/technical/20170407100356.php), [...Blogの設定](https://support.wix.com/ja/%E6%96%B0-wix-blog/%E6%96%B0-wix-blog-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A), [...Blogでの記事管理](https://support.wix.com/ja/%E6%96%B0-wix-blog/%E6%96%B0-wix-blog-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86), [カテゴリーが50以上...](https://support.wix.com/ja/article/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C50%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%EF%BC%882019%E5%B9%B46%E6%9C%8813%E6%97%A5%EF%BC%89)

Comment: @kunif  親切にリンクをつけてくださり、ありがとうございます。私も一通り調べて機能がないことは理解したのですが、何か別の策を知っている方がいればと思い、質問いたしました。何も策がない場合にはブログは別の物を代用しようかと思います。